# How does jackson implement json transfer to object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to test jackson. I have a class that no setters and no constructors with params(only have a default constructor and getters).

Code like the following:

```
public class BeanA {
  private int attr1;
  private int attr2;

  public BeanA(){
  }

  public int getAttr1(){
    return attr1;
  }

  public int getAttr2(){
    return attr2;
  }

}
```

I used `jackson` to transfer json to `BeanA`.`jackson` can work well.

I can't understand `jackson` how to assign values without setter and constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection, by assigning to the fields directly.

Example of what it's doing internally:

```
Object o = BeanA.class.newInstance();
Field attr1 = BeanA.class.getDeclaredField("attr1");
attr1.setAccessible(true);
attr1.set(o, 42);
System.out.println(((BeanA) o).getAttr1());
```

Comment: Thank you. That's amazing can change visibility.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @JB User there are various configuration & defaults Jackson apply for serialization/deserialization. Have look at the below links

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesSerialization and 
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureAutoDetect

If you override the Feature "CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS" to false you will get the error you expected.